# Navigation Bar Top Item, not showing back bar button, the left is showing when created but it doesnt show the arrow <

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

The code is in Objective-C and I would like to have the arrow appearing without adding an image as a src.
I've done projects where it appears automatically when changing the controller.

Here I created the left bar button:

```
 navItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(returnToPreviousScreen)];
```

This is showing great and working as desired, but it doesnt show the < arrow on the left side of the text.
If I try to create a backbar button it doesnt work at all; doesnt even shows it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting *backBarButtonItem* property on *navigationItem*, but instead of doing it in the view controller that was pushed, do it in the previous view controller. You can set the target and selector to nil, it won't have any effect when set on *backBarButtonItem*.